# Vuetify: Hide a skeleton loader after a element loads

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been trying to create a simple skeleton loader in Vuetify that is shown while the document's resources (like images) are being loaded and then hidden (replaced with a `<v-card>`) when everything is fully loaded.

Currently, I have this `<v-skeleton-loader>`:

```
<v-skeleton-loader v-if="loading == true" :loading="loading" transition="fade-transition" type="card">
</v-skeleton-loader>
```

My `v-card` element uses `v-show` like this:

```
<v-card max-width="344" v-show="loaded">
```

For reactive properties, I have:

```
data: () => ({
    loading: true,
    loaded: false
})
```

I am trying to update the values of those properties using the `updated` lifecycle hook of Vue.js:

```
updated: function() {
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
        this.loading = false;
        this.loaded = true;
    }

}
```

Currently, Vue Devtools tells me that the properties are not being updated with their new values, defined in the `updated` hook. How can I change that so the values are properly updated when the `readyState` of the DOM has changed to `complete`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`updated`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) hook is called only when a component is updated. Vue lifecycle isn't tied to DOM events. If there were no updates after page load, `updated` won't be triggered.

This can be done with regular DOM event listener:

```
created() {
  const readyHandler = () => {
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
        this.loading = false;
        this.loaded = true;
        document.removeEventListener('readystatechange', readyHandler);
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', readyHandler);

  readyHandler(); // in case the component has been instantiated lately after loading
}
```

Comment: If someone who facing document is not define, You could try to put the mounted hook instead of created hook. [reference](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/442#issuecomment-388661319)

Comment: @meekittipol That's specific to SSR but yes, that's what needs to be done if that's the case.

Comment: The only example I found that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must observe document.readyState:

```
mounted: function() {
  var that = this;

  if (document.readyState === 'complete')
    this.$set(that, 'loaded', true);
  else
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
      if (document.readyState === 'complete')
        that.$set(that, 'loaded', true);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <v-card class="card" v-if="loaded">
   <h2>xxxx</h2>
 </v-card>
 <v-sheet class="pa-3" v-else>
  <v-skeleton-loader
    class="mx-auto"
    type="card"
  ></v-skeleton-loader>
</v-sheet>
```